# Lock table while inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking

I have a large table that get populated from a view. This is done because the view takes a long time to run and it is easier to have the data readily available in a table. A procedure is run every so often that updates the table.

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE LargeTable

 INSERT INTO LargeTable
 SELECT * 
 FROM viewLargeView
 WITH (HOLDLOCK)
```

I would like to lock this table when inserting so if someone tries to select a record they will not receive none after the truncate. The lock I am using seems to lock the view and not the table.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: What about opening a transaction before the insert and closing it after ?

Comment: When opening a transaction can another user select from the table?

Comment: FYI, I'd recommend that you use DELETE instead of TRUNCATE, as TRUNCATE is a DDL, instead of a DML like DELETE, and thus requires greater permissions.  Plus, if you wrap this in a Transaction (which is the correct answer to your question), they will effectively perform the same.

Comment: Plus, TRUNCATE TABLE within a transaction can lock-up your databases metadata for the length of the transaction, which can result in bad juju if it gets blocked.  If this is operational (off-hours), then it's probably OK, but if its running while you have users interacting with the database, you might have problems...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION t_Transaction

 TRUNCATE TABLE LargeTable

 INSERT INTO LargeTable
 SELECT * 
 FROM viewLargeView
  WITH (HOLDLOCK)

 COMMIT TRANSACTION t_Transaction
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t_Transaction
END CATCH
```

Comment: Don't think this would do anything at all.  The `truncate` is not affected by a transaction, and an insert all by itself is also a transaction, even if you don't specify one.

Comment: Actually TRUNCATEs are rolled back with some caveats.  See [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/26/sql-server-truncate-cant-be-rolled-back-using-log-files-after-transaction-session-is-closed/)

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  "TRUNCATE TABLE cannot be ran inside of a transaction."

Comment: @Emo, that applies only for:
"In Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse, TRUNCATE TABLE cannot be ran inside of a transaction."

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now

Answer (score 9):

It's true that your correct locking hint affects the source view.

To make it so that nobody can read from the table while you're inserting:

```
insert into LargeTable with (tablockx)
...
```

You don't have to do anything to make the table look empty until after the insert completes.  An insert always runs in a transaction, and no other process can read uncommitted rows, unless they explicitly specify `with (nolock)` or `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted`.  There is no way to protect from that as far as I know.