# Will the Transactions in MSSQL lock the tables

Tags: php, sql-server, transactions

Will the Transactions in MSSQL lock the tables? If so, are locks held for the duration of the entire transaction or only held for the duration of the statement execution. Below is a Transaction example (ignore any syntax errors)

```
if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $dbConnection ) === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}
$query = "INSERT INTO order_table (name,description,created_at) VALUES ('test_name','test_Transaction','some_date')";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($dbConnection ,$query) or die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());

$query = "INSERT INTO other_details_table (order_id,details) VALUES ('1234','order_details')";
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($dbConnection ,$query) or die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());

sleep('20'); // used to delay the transaction time

/* If both queries were successful, commit the transaction. */
/* Otherwise, rollback the transaction. */
if( $stmt1 && $stmt2 ) {
 sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
 echo "Transaction committed.<br />";
 } else {
 sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
 echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
}
```

When the above Transaction is in process, I tried to insert a record  in to table 'order_table', it inserted successfully. How do I lock the tables which are in Transaction and unlock them after commit or rollback.

Comment: transactions hide the relevant new records from other users until the transaction is committed. anyone doing a select on those tables while you're sleeping wouldn't see the new data.

Comment: look like a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842253/lock-table-while-inserting

Answer (score 0):

Transactions will lock a table until the transaction is committed. Even if the query ends the transaction will still remain open if the Transaction hasn't been committed or rolled back. As long as the query hits COMMIT or ROLLBACK the tables will be unlocked.

In your code though I don't see where you  have opened a Transaction if you don't open a transaction then SQL Server will error out at the commit and rollback because MSSQL is smart enough to close the transaction by itself if you have not explicitly opened a transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am opening transaction like this sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $dbConnection ) where $dbConnection is valid connection. I am not sure if it is correct or not

Comment: I am not sure if that would work or not. I thought you were talking about just the SQL itself. I am sure if your connection string is correct that it will work.